# Can I stream media from one Plex server to another Plex server?

Tags: macos, video, streaming

I have Plex on a laptop and I can use Plex for the iDevices to stream media to them.

Can I do the same with Plex on another computer around the house like ZumoCast?

Comment: Are you saying that Plex media server A has access to your media, and Plex media server B doesn't?  And you want to stream media from A while connected to B (B streams from A, and you stream from B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any device with the plex front end, ie, iDevice, apple TV, LG medialink, & apple computers, can see any Plex server that is running on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For more complete information:  http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Plex_Nine_Configurations_test

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, just login Plex on another computer, and access it, you can stream media date from Plex to your iDevices.